# Expected value of a wiener process on an infinite time horizon with a barrier

Tags: risk-neutral-measure, martingale, wienerprocess

Say I have a wiener process with $X(0) = X_0>0$ and the dynamics
\begin{equation}
dX(t) = 
\begin{cases}
-\mu dt + \sigma X(t) dW(t)^{\mathbb{Q}} & \mathrm{for\ } X(t)>0\\
0 & \mathrm{otherwise}\\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Where $\mu \geq 0$.

What can I say about the expected value of $E^{\mathbb{Q}}[X(T)]$ as $T \to \infty$? Naturally one would expect $X=0$ to happen eventually, but is it almost surely so?

Comment: yes. This is the classic problem gambler's ruin. Say we ignore the drift; then by symmetry, we have an equal change to go to $2X_0$ as to 0 - i.e. $50/50$. Once we're at $2X_0$, we again have an equal change to double our money as we do to hit zero (the change to hit zero after doubling once but before twice is 1/4). This series continues, and 0.5+0.25+0.125+... -> 1 - i.e. the probability to hit 0 goes to one. If you add in negative drift, it can only increase the rate of convergence. It's all in [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler's_ruin#Reasons_for_the_four_results).

Comment: The answer is actually on wikipedia, in a different page, it's caleld the [risk of ruin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risk_of_ruin#Risk_of_ruin_for_investors).